# Undefined cache functions in my custom plugin

Tags: plugin-development, cache

I am making a plugin that make a HTTP call to my API, I want this call be cached an tried using this way:

```
static function get_info(){
    $cache = wp_cache_get( $username, "action" );
    if(!cache){
        $cache = file_get_contents(...);
        wp_cache_set( $username, $cache, "action", 900 );
    }
    return $cache;
}
```

When I run this code (this php file are inside my plugin) I am getting

> "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
> wp_cache_get()"

I have to maque a require from wp-includes.php cache file? Or maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Where is this code? Are you sending an AJAX request directly to a file in your plugin by any chance?

Comment: I read your comment and understand whats were taking place here.. I was testing the php that I will call using ajax directly in the browser and in this case wordpress functions are missing. Sorry for the question